# PL/SQL to PostgreSQL conversion

Tags: postgresql, plsql

Please help me to convert this PL/SQL into PostgreSQL. Thank you very much.

**Prime Numbers**

```
CREATE TABLE n (n NUMBER);<br/>
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE prime_number (n NUMBER)<br/> 
IS <br/>
prime_count   NUMBER       := 0;<br/>
y             VARCHAR2 (1) := 'N';<br/>
BEGIN<br/>
IF n >= 1
THEN
  prime_count := 1;

  INSERT INTO n
       VALUES (2);
END IF;

IF n >= 2
THEN
  prime_count := 2;

  INSERT INTO n
       VALUES (2);
END IF;

IF n >= 3
THEN
  FOR i IN 4 .. n * n * n
  LOOP
     y := 'N';

     FOR j IN 2 .. CEIL (SQRT (i))
     LOOP
        IF (MOD (i, j) = 0)
        THEN
           y := 'Y';
           EXIT;
        END IF;
     END LOOP;

     IF (y = 'N')
     THEN
        INSERT INTO n
             VALUES (i);

        COMMIT;
        prime_count := prime_count + 1;
        EXIT WHEN prime_count = n;
     END IF;
  END LOOP;
END IF;<br/>
END;


BEGIN<br/>
   prime_number (1000000);<br/>
END;
```

Comment: Firstly you don't convert PL/SQL to PostgreSQL probably to PL/pgSQL. Secondly if you want someone to just do the job for you as well specify a pay rate.

Comment: Sorry I meant PL/SQL to PL/PgSQL

Comment: This can be done with a simple SQL query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/7779

Comment: thanks, but your code will not handle large numbers. Max 10k primes! Not even near 1 mil.